# Creating sums of elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list $(d_1, d_2, .. d_k)$ and I want to create all sums that I get for adding only two elements for my list $(d_1+d_2, d_1+d_3,...d_{k-1}+d_k)$. The `RotateLeft` function gives me only some of my sums and I need all of them.

Answer (score 8):

```
l = {a, b, c, d};
Plus @@@ Subsets[l, {2}]
(*
  {a + b, a + c, a + d, b + c, b + d, c + d}
*)
```

**edit**

Some timings

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

Come downvote @Verde

```
l = {a, b, c, d}

l~Subsets~{2}~Total~{2}
```

Comment: (deleted comment)

Comment: This one is six times faster than the `Plus @@@` solution, twice as fast as the `Outer` solution, and three times faster than the `Table` solution.

Comment: And ten times slower than `Total /@ Subsets[l, {2}]`

Comment: @whuber `l = RandomReal[1, 
  10^3]; {(Timing@(l~Subsets~{2}~Total~{2}))[[1]], (Timing[
    Plus @@@ Subsets[l, {2}]])[[1]]}` -> {2.89, 0.547} ...

Comment: @Verde You're right: that's astounding, given how similar the `Total /@` and `~Total~2` constructs are!.

Comment: @whuber posted some timings in my answer

Answer (score 4):

```
l = {a, b, c, d};
```

Let's make use of pattern matching ( even though there are faster methods especially for list manipulations) :

```
ReplaceList[ l, {___, x_, ___, y_, ___} -> x + y]
```

> ```
> {a + b, a + c, a + d, b + c, b + d, c + d}
> ```

Typically, efficiency of pattern matching solutions is worse than that of functional approach, nevertheless we point out a remarkable feature of the result of `ReplaceList`: it is  identical with other (functional) methods, e.g. (taking a longer list) we have:

```
ls = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, , m, n, o, p, q, r, s};

ReplaceList[ls, {___, x_, ___, y_, ___} -> x + y] == 
Plus @@@ Subsets[ls, {2}] == ls~Subsets~{2}~Total~{2}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Something like :

```
data = {a, b, c, d}; 

Flatten[Table[data[[i]] + data[[j]], {i, 1, Length[data] - 1}, {j, i + 1, Length[data]}],1]

(* {a + b, a + c, a + d, b + c, b + d, c + d} *)
```

Alternatively (plus suggestion from @Oleksandr R.) :

```
Total /@ Subsets[data, {2}]
```

And just because `RotateLeft` was mentioned :

```
Union[Flatten[Total /@ Subsets[NestList[RotateLeft[#] &, data, Length[data] - 1], {2}], 1]]
```

Comment: The third one seems a memory hog :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to show that there's more than one way to do things in *Mathematica*:

```
test = {a, b, c, d, e};
Total /@ (Join @@ MapIndexed[Drop[#1, First[#2]] &,
          Outer[List, test, test]])
   {a + b, a + c, a + d, a + e, b + c, b + d, b + e, c + d, c + e, d + e}
```

Of course, Oleksandr's and Verde's suggestions are the more compact way of going about it.

Answer (score 2):

Since somebody mentioned timings...

```
Module[{x = Outer[Plus, l, l]},
 Flatten[x[[#, # + 1 ;;]] & /@ Range[Length@x - 1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Subsets[Plus @@ l, {2}]
(* or Subsets[Total@l, {2}] *)
```

> {a + b, a + c, a + d, b + c, b + d, c + d}