# How can I manipulate with elements inside sublists if sublists of different lenght?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some kind of output like this: `{{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {1, 5, 25}}`. I would like to be able to enter in each sublist and make sums of every two elements in sublists, for example my desired output would be `{{6}, {14}, {6, 30, 26}}`. I can export these sublists in txt file, but I don't know if this is even necessary.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much on your help!

Comment: Try a combination of `Map` and any of the suggestions in your previous question. You are very close.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time [you will be able to do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Answer (score 7):

Imagine you have these data:

```
data = Range /@ Range[2, 5]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

Then this will do:

```
(Plus @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ data
```

> {{3}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9}}

Application `f@@@expr` is equivalent to `Apply[f,expr,{1}]`. It will simultaneously map over internal elements and replace their heads with `f`. Using this on you data:

```
(Plus @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ {{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {1, 5, 25}}
```

> {{6}, {14}, {6, 26, 30}}

With the same success you could use any functions offered to you for [your privious answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10196). For example:

```
#~Subsets~{2}~Total~{2} & /@ {{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {1, 5, 25}}
```

> {{6}, {14}, {6, 26, 30}}

or from @Verde & @OleksandrR. comments:

```
(Total /@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ {{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {1, 5, 25}}
```

> {{6}, {14}, {6, 26, 30}}

Comment: Probably `(Total /@ Subsets[#, {2}]) & /@ {{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {1, 5, 25}}` is faster

Comment: @Verde yes, added, thank you.

Comment: `Map[Total, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ {{1, 5}, {1, 13}, {1, 5, 25}}, {2}]` works, too.