# Any built-in function to generate successive sublists from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, sets

Given

```
lst = {a, b, c, d}
```

I'd like to generate

```
{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}
```

but using built-in functions only, such as `Subsets`, `Partitions`, `Tuples`, `Permutations` or any other such command you can choose. But it has to be done only using built-in commands. You can use a pure function, if inside a built-in command, i.e. part of the command arguments. That is OK.

It is of course trivial to do this by direct coding. One way can be

```
lst[[1 ;; #]] & /@ Range[Length[lst]]
(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}  *)
```

or even

```
LowerTriangularize[Table[lst, {i, Length[lst]}]] /. 0 -> Sequence @@ {}
(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}  *)
```

But I have the feeling there is a command to do this more directly as it looks like a common operation, but my limited search could not find one so far.

Sorry in advance if this was asked before. Searching is hard for such general questions.

Comment: How about something like `Rest@FoldList[Append, {}, {a, b, c, d}]`? More succinctly, `FoldList[Append,{First@#},Rest[#]]&[{a,b,c,d}]`

Comment: Related:  [(SO8861517)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8861517/618728),  [(7511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/121), [(8528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8528/121),
[(10196)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10196/121),
[(23677)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23677/121),
[(32404)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32404/121),
[(37312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37312/121),
[(72613)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72613/121),
[(87288)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87288/121)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
 lst={a,b,c,d};
 ReplaceList[lst,{x__, ___} :> {x}]
```

Speaking of "common operation":

```
 Table[lst[[;; i]], {i, Length@lst}]
```

Comment: I was playing with a pattern based solution, +1 for ReplaceList.

Comment: +1, there's your 20k, btw. I've always had trouble with `ReplaceList`, and for me it is the second most annoying function that sounds useful. The most annoying being `MapAt` ... Although, I've more success with `MapAt` than `ReplaceList`.

Comment: @rcollyer, @image_doctor, Nasser, thanks for the votes. Rcollyer, for me too -- it always takes several attempts until I get `MapAt` and `ReplaceList` right. And, i don't remember `ReplaceList` winning any speed contests.

Comment: I found `Position` is a great way to get `MapAt` to behave itself, provided you can figure out how to specify what positions you need ...

Comment: @rcollyer Be [careful](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node292.html) with `MapAt` though.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin absolutely. My primary use has been to change a random element out of a randomly generated list of arbitrary (and random) shape. So, `MapAt` is useful as I don't need to know how to specify the part correctly, and efficiency takes a back seat to just being able to do it correctly consistently.

Answer (score 19):

A variant using `Take`.

```
list~Take~# & /@ Range@Length@list
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

One using `NestList`:

```
NestList[Most, list, Length@list - 1]
```

> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b}, {a}}

Answer (score 17):

`Subsets` takes an optional 3rd argument as `Subsets[list, {n}, k]` that gives you the `k`th sublist of length `n`. Since your sublists are in sequence, you'll always need `k = 1`. You can then use this as:

```
MapIndexed[First@Subsets[list, #2, 1] &, list]
(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}} *)
```

Another alternative would be:

```
Reverse@Most@NestWhileList[Most, list, # != {} &]
```

Comment: Why are you using `MapIndexed`? Why not `Subsets[list, #, 1][[1]]& /@ Range[Length@list]`? It seems cleaner.

Comment: "Cleaner" is subjective and in this case, I positively dislike having to use `Range@Length@foo` when I don't have to. Far cleaner to use `MapIndexed` and ignore `#1`

Comment: +1. But the real clean solution here is to use linked lists, since all of the suggested ones have quadratic complexity in the length of the list.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I thought of something like `Flatten /@ Rest@FoldList[List, {}, {a, b, c, d}]`, but it was similar to your solution above and was hoping you'd post it

Comment: [`FoldList`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16571/52) by itself works.

Comment: @rm-rf Somehow I did not expect so much excitement about this topic, so many answers. I could as well post it indeed. Perhaps I will. But my solution suffers from the same flaw as others.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin My "interest" is in getting [a gold badge](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/list-manipulation/topusers) some day... hopefully without answering too many low hanging fruit :D (damn you for guilt-tripping me :P). But more seriously, I do like list-manipulation questions that are generic (i.e., not overly data specific)... it provides an excellent opportunity to learn different techniques (some that you might not even expect)

Comment: Actually, @rcollyer posted it, so problem solved :). Re: gold badge - I've got one already, on SO :). Seriously, I am much less interested in list manipulations in Mathematica now than I used to be. I found that things that make it hard for me personally to code in M are mostly elsewhere (and it is not always obvious what they are, for a given problem).

Comment: I think that most of us like list manipulation because M has an outstanding support for them, so that our programming flow can be very smooth. For a number of other things (handling state, implementing data structures with certain characteristics, scaling codebase to larger size, etc), the support is perhaps not so great, so one has to overcome significant mental barriers and these topics are less attractive to most M users. But this is what interests me more at present, since this is what stands in my way.

Comment: It looks like I need one more question for a copper badge, but a gold one would be nice, too. I guess I need to start answering questions more.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I need to study up on list manipulation algorithms a bit to consider myself "good" at them. Recursion still drives me a bit nuts.

Comment: @rcollyer I don't consider myself good at them either, just OK. The problem is that Mathematica's execution model often creates rather unnatural preferences for the algorithms implementations. But recursion is very powerful. Actually, I don't know what I would do without it for many problems. It was very important ingredient for RLink, for one thing.

Comment: I think my objection the the `MapIndexed` form is that you are carrying around a reference to `list`, mapping over `list`, yet only using the indices. So, yes, I think `f /@ Range@Length@list` is cleaner because it requires less work to understand it quickly. While the `MapIndexed` form is still quick, it takes more time to parse it mentally.

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure this wins any speed contests, but it is a purely functional solution:

```
FoldList[#1~Join~{#2} &, {First@#}, Rest@#]& @ {a, b, c, d, e}
(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d, e}} *)
```

Comment: Ok, since you posted this, I am liberated from doing that (I gave it in comments to the question), and can happily upvote : +1.

Comment: +1, a variation: `FoldList[Flatten@{##} &, {First@list}, Rest@list]`? or `FoldList[Sequence @@@ {##} &, {First@list}, Rest@list]`?

Comment: @kguler I'd migrate `list` outside of `FoldList`, but I hate writing more than I have too.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin teach me to look at the comments before I post something ... Speed wise, though, is `Join` or `Append` faster. What about kguler's alternatives?

Comment: I think @kguler's use of `ReplaceList` is very elegant. For generic lists, should be quite fast. For packed arrays, `Join` and `Append` should be faster, since `ReplaceList` can not make use of those and will likely unpack.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think `ReplaceList` is a brilliant use of that function. But, I had more in mind the speed differences between the `FoldList` implementations.

Comment: @rcollyer I did not benchmark (`FoldList`), but I don't expect them (differences) to be very significant.

Answer (score 10):

What about `Accumulate`:

```
Function[lst, {{lst[[1]]}}~Join~Rest[Accumulate[lst] /. Plus -> List]]@{a, b, c, d, e}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't accept a custom function other than `Plus` and will not work for numerical list...

Answer (score 6):

A variant using Partition:

```
First[Partition[list,#]]& /@ Range@Length@list
```

Answer (score 5):

A joke solution:

```
Outer[Take, {{a, b, c, d, e}}, Range[5], 1] // First
```

Answer (score 5):

```
FromLetterNumber@Range@Range[4]
```

> {{a},{a,b},{a,b,c},{a,b,c,d}}

**Edit**

On looking at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163697/106) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) (see also part-2 of the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16560/106) by [image_doctor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/776/image-doctor) below).

And see also the comment by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16571/106) answer by [rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer).

```
FoldList[Flatten[{##}] &, Nothing, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

Answer (score 3):

This is not a built-in function to do it but it fits the criteria of only using buil-in functions. It avoids using patterns, mapping constructs and such things.

Maybe in the future ListCorrelate can accepts functions instead of heads (e.g. applying Plus to a list by default). I think that would make it more useful (but I am a beginner Mathematica user, so who am I to hold such opinions).

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};
DeleteCases[
 ListCorrelate[lst, ConstantArray[1, Length@lst], 1, 0, Times, 
  List], 0, {2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, c, d};

MapAt[List, 1] @ MapApply[List] @ Accumulate @ list
```

{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

`MapApply` came with V 13.1

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases` and `Accumulate`:

```
list = {a, b, c, d};
Cases[Accumulate[list], s_ :> If[AtomQ[s], {s}, List @@ s]]

(*{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}*)
```

Also, using `Drop`:

```
Reverse[Table[Drop[#, -i], {i, 0, Length@# - 1}]] &@list

(*{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}*)
```

Also, usin `TakeList`:

```
Table[Sequence @@ TakeList[#, {i}], {i, Length@#}] &@list

(*{{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}*)
```