# matrix with IF/THEN condition

Tags: matrix, code-generation

How to generate all posible matrices with some conditions on the elements?

I need to make for given $n$ all $n\times n$ matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ with three conditions:

> I. $a_{ij}=+1$ or $0$ or $-1$.
>
> II. $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$
>
> III. if $a_{ij}\geq 0$ and $a_{jk}\geq 0$, then $a_{ik}\geq 0$; and $a_{ik}=0$ only if $a_{ij}=a_{jk}=0$

The only way I see is to expand these three conditions to equivalent but more elementary eight IF/ELSE conditions:

> 1) if $a_{ij}=+1$, then $a_{ji}=-1$
>
> 2) if $a_{ij}=+1$ and $a_{jk}=+1$, then $a_{ik}=+1$
>
> 3) $a_{ii}=0$
>
> 4) if $a_{ij}=0$, then $a_{ji}=0$
>
> 5) if $a_{ij}=0$ and $a_{jk}=0$, then $a_{ik}=0$
>
> 6) if $a_{ij}=+1$ and $a_{jk}=0$, then $a_{ik}=+1$
>
> 7) if $a_{ij}=0$ and $a_{jk}=+1$, then $a_{ik}=+1$
>
> 8) $a_{ij}=+1$ or $0$ or $-1$

And to generate for given $n$ all possible matrices, make it antisymmetric, then make all permutates of $+1$, $0$, $-1$; and after that deleting unnecessary cases with help of cycles. But it quickly became too complicated. Is there any more natural way?

PS this problem arised from [this SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37845/how-to-implement-kemeny-young-method-rank-aggregation-problem) and appeals to [this book](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015002661802;view=1up;seq=21).

Comment: I think you may have formulated conditions stronger than what you actually want. Your second one implies all diagonal entries are zero. Your third, taking k=i, then implies all off-diagonal entries are zero. Possibly that one is to be restricted to {i,j,k} all pairwise distinct?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  III. can be explained detailed by 2), 5), 6), 7).

Comment: Maybe. But not in a way that I follow.

Comment: Excuse me. If I understand your question, you are right that pairwise are distinct. In fact, indexes denote different objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A possible approach would be with dynamic programming. Start with only zeros on the main diagonal. Try a value in the 1,2 position. compute all other entries that the new one forces to take a specific value, and proceed in that way. Every time you reach a dead end or a new viable matrix, backtrack to the last new non-forced entry (deleting all values that were forced by its prior value), change it to a new value, continue. This is a sketchy outline but it might give a reasonably efficient way to generate all possibilites.