# How to get multiplication of the elements of a specific list/Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, calculus-and-analysis

Assume there is a list:

```
List1={a,b,c,d};
```

Then I want to get these calculation:

```
Output1= a
Output2= a*b
Output3= a*b*c
Output4= a*b*c*d
```

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: FoldList[Times, 1, List1] // Rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d};

Rest[FoldList[Times, 1, list1]]

Scan[Print, %]
```

> `a`
>   `a b`
>   `a b c`
>   `a b c d`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Accumulate`

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d};

Times @@@ Accumulate[list1]
(* or Accumulate[list1] /. Plus -> Times *)
```

> {a, a b, a b c, a b c d}

... or `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list1, {x__, ___} :> Times[x]]
```

> {a, a b, a b c, a b c d}

Comment: I am not sure it can be assumed that unwanted evaluation will not take place here.

Answer (score 3):

My version of Bob Hanlon's comment solution:

```
list1 = {a, b, c, d};

FoldList[Times, list1]

% // Column
```

> ```
> {a, a b, a b c, a b c d}
>
> a
> a b
> a b c
> a b c d
> ```

Reference: [Shorter syntax for Fold and FoldList?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)