# Generating a sequence of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

I have learnt how to generate a sequence of numbers, but now I come across a question whether it is possible to generate e sequence of lists. Say, I would like to generate {1},{1,2},{1,2,3},...,{1,2,3,...,10}. How can I do that?

Comment: `Range /@ Range[10]`  :-D

Comment: @JasonB: What? Hahaha... That really works. I am new in Mathematica. And haven't learnt that symbol '\@'. Could you explain?

Comment: So `Range[x]` will give `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,......x}`, and `/@` is the infix notation for `Map`.  As an example, look `f /@ {1, 2, 3}` gives `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}`.  So in the above, `Range[10]` gives `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`, and then I'm just mapping `Range` onto that list

Comment: Wow. Smart way!! Thanks JasonB :D

Comment: at least closely related: [generate successive sublists from a list?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16556/5478)

Comment: Or `Range@Range[10]`.  See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html) under 'neat examples'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Table[Range[i], {i, 1, 10}]

(*  {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4,
   5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```

or this:

```
Table[Table[k, {k, 1, i}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

with the same result.
Have fun!

Comment: Yes. That generates the same result. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

My entry into the obfuscated *Mathematica* competition for April, 2016.

```
rangeList[n_Integer?Positive] := NestList[Join[#, {Last[#] + 1}] &, {1}, n - 1]

rangeList[5]
```

> `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}`

Too bad I'm posting this on April 15 rather than April 1.

Comment: `FoldList[(Flatten@*List), Nothing, Range[10]] == Range@Range[10]`