# Native function that gives sequential sub-sequences of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I am very surprised not to find this function in the help (or in other questions on this site, which come close)

Is there a Mathematica function `f` such that

```
f[{a,b,c,d}] = {{a},{a,b},{a,b,c},{a,b,c,d}}
```

or must I construct it?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your quick answers! Going with myfun[x_] := Take[x, #] & /@ Range[Length[x]]

Comment: Recommend `myfun[x_?VectorQ] := ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Take[{a, b, c, d}, #] & /@ Range[4]

(* {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility:

```
Reverse @ NestList[Most, {a,b,c,d}, 3]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

Comment: In the same 'vein': `FoldList[Flatten[{##}] &, Nothing, {a, b, c, d}]`

Answer (score 5):

Two ideas

```
f1[l_List] := Rest[FoldList[Append, {}, l]];
f2[l_List] := Table[Take[l, i], {i, Length[l]}]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d}, {x__, ___} :> {x}]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

```
Table[{a, b, c, d}[[;; i]], {i, 4}]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

```
{a, b, c, d}[[;; #]] & /@ Range@4
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 4, 1, -1, {}]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

```
Extract[{a, b, c, d}, List /@ Range @ Range @ 4]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16568/5478

Comment: @Kuba, I knew I have seen this question before:)

Answer (score 4):

For something different

```
f[x_List] := 
 LowerTriangularize@ConstantArray[x, Length[x]] /. 0 -> Nothing

f[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c, d}}