# Partition list into sublists of decreasing length

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, I would like to partition `{1,2,3,4,5}` into

```
{1}
{1,2}
{1,2,3}
{1,2,3,4}
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

with just one line of code. Is there any way to do this? I am working with a much larger data set and do not want to have to separate the list into shorter and shorter lists manually. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `ReplaceList[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__, ___} :> {x}]`.  By the way this question is a duplicate; help finding the original is appreciated.

Comment: Related: [(7511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/121),
[(10196)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10196/121),
[(23677)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23677/121),
[(32404)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32404/121),
[(37312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37312/121),
[(72613)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72613/121),
[(87288)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87288/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FoldList[Join, List /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
myList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Reverse@NestList[Most, myList, Length[myList]-1]
```

Of the four solutions posted, this one is the fastest on large sets.  Using `Timing` and the data set `Range[10^3]`, the execution times are:

- `Table[Take[list, i], {i, Length[list]}]` 0.00351 seconds
- `Reverse@NestList[Most, myList, Length[myList]-1]`  0.002089 seconds
- `FoldList[Join, List /@ Range[10^3]]` 0.002965 seconds
- `x[[;; #]] & /@ Range@Length@x` 0.002537 seconds

Answer (score 2):

```
list={1,2,3,4,5};
Table[Take[list, i], {i, Length[list]}]
```

will give you

> ```
> {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
x[[;; #]] & /@ Range@Length@x

(* {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
```